A very interesting food chain
Below there are 9 different animals, that are at the very top of the foodchain. However, there is one big problem: they are starving! They haven't eaten their favorite prey for days! You have to help them, maybe they will revive...

A bird called Enun that's hunting domesticated animals (1)
A rodent called Ev that's hunting animals much bigger than itself (6)
An insect called Fyb that's hunting reptiles (5)
A large mammal called Dwis that's hunting tiny insects (4)
A reptile called Hone that's hunting mammals (3)
A reptile called Osi that's hunting animals that are a little bigger (4)
A smart animal called Phd (pun intended) that's hunting animals they never meet (2)
A reptile called Ta that's hunting primates (9)
A little bird called Ror that's hunting insects (1)


How do we call these animals?

The names of the animals

must be combined with the names of their prey and unscrambled.


A bird called Enun that's hunting domesticated animals (1)


ENUN + PIG = PENGUIN


A rodent called Ev that's hunting animals much bigger than itself (6)


EV + BEAR = BEAVER


An insect called Fyb that's hunting reptiles (5)


FYB + TURTLE = BUTTERFLY


A large mammal called Dwis that's hunting tiny insects (4)


DWIS + BEETLE = WILDEBEEST


A reptile called Hone that's hunting mammals (3)


HONE + CAMEL + CHAMELEON


A reptile called Osi that's hunting animals that are a little bigger (4)


OSI + OTTER + TORTOISE


A smart animal called Phd (pun intended) that's hunting animals they never meet (2)


PHD + LION = DOLPHIN


A reptile called Ta that's hunting primates (9)


TA + GORILLA = ALLIGATOR


A little bird called Ror that's hunting insects (1)


ROR + WASP + SPARROW

Finally,

indexing into the names of the animals reveals that we call them PREDATORS.


Just curious, what was the first one you got? And which one was the most difficult to find?

@Lezzup I started with Fyb because it was an interesting combination of letters, and it was the first one I got. The hardest for me was Osi because I had no clue what the prey was.
